# Ruby On Rails. Broke Application and IDK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I am working on a ROR "intermediate" project I found on medium/freecodecamp.

I have gone through each page and line number in the logs and I'm still getting an error. One thing that I've never seen was modifying the app/helpers/* files. When I did this it added >>>>>>head & ">>>>>Helper" in a lot of files. 
I'm not sure what is going on so I'm trying to be as detailed as possible about what could possibly be be the culprit
Here is the GitHub link in case that helps...https://github.com/Mbartlett413/myblog

Right now when I look on my local host I see,
 "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

When I look in my terminal I see this, `Cannot render console from XX.XX.XX ...<br/>
Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.3ms)
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1597ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)...<br/>`

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "  }": expected "}", was ""): <br/>
4:     <title>Blog</title> <br/>
5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %> <br/>
6:  <br/>
7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> <br/>
8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> <br/>
9:   </head> <br/>
10: 

app/assets/stylesheets/partials/layout/navigation.scss:75 <br/>
app/assets/stylesheets/partials/layout:1 <br/>
app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:23 <br/>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1682161864386442755_69890208520440'
```

Comment: i think you are facing issue with git conflicts, check this link https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/

Comment: When I run git status, it returns my branch is up-to-date with origin/master.... nothing to commit, working directory is clean. All other branches have been deleted after i merged.

Comment: Just move back to previous commit . To get the list of all commit run `git logs` and to move back to particular commit just run `git checkout <commit id>`. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move back to previous commit . To get the list of all commit run `git logs` and to move back to particular commit just run `git checkout <commit-id>`. To checkout previous link [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely seeing git conflicts.  Whenever you see something like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
//some code
=======
//new code
>>>>>>> new-branch-name
```

Git is telling there is a conflict between the HEAD and your working branch.  This happens when git is unable to automatically merge the two branches and needs you to decide which version is preferred.

After all is completed, every instance of `>>>>>>`, `======`, and `<<<<<<<` should be removed, and you can run

```
git commit
```

to complete the merge.

Comment: I believe I have handled all merge issues, and deleted all instances and ran git commit... App still wont work...

Comment: Same errors as listed above. When I resolve all the merge issues, add, commit and push, it still doesn't change. I must have missed something and now I can't find it.

Comment: You do have a missing end bracket on your `body{` declaration in the navigation.scss file.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up checking out an older commit, took two steps back on this. Thanks for the help guys.